# HTML5 tiene gramática pero lógica matemática o logíca estructural

Tags: html, html5

Mientras leía este [documento del W3C](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/), me encontré una parte que me dio curiosidad:

> Similarly, just as natural languages have grammatical rules for how different words can be used, HTML has rules for where and how each element and attribute can be used.

Que se puede traducir como:

> Del mismo modo, tal y como los lenguajes naturales tiene reglas gramaticales sobre cómo las diferentes palabras pueden ser usadas, HTML tiene reglas para dónde y cómo cada elemento y atributo puede ser usado.

Lógicamente lo entiendo que HTML no es como lenguajes como JavaScript o Java. Entonces mi pregunta es:

¿HTML tiene un lógica matemática para posicionar los elementos de una forma y orden lógico (matemático) para que tenga un sentido currente el documento?¿O es solamente un orden jerárquico del DOM? (porque creo yo que el texto se refiere a la trama lógica que tiene en el DOM una página web)

¿Alguien experto en HTML5 podría explicarme?

Comment: El DOM por naturaleza te mostrara en orden jerárquico, pero esto puede cambiar con CSS. Así de simple.
Html es un lenguaje de marcado.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con lógica matemática/estructural? El HTML tiene su gramática, como todo lenguaje. Hay reglas que te dicen qué puedes poner dentro de cada elemento y qué no

Comment: El texto se refiere a que cada elemento HTML tiene una definicion para declararlo asi como sus propiedades y elementos hijos que puede contener

Comment: Si tiene una definición gramática de cómo definir cada elemento, atributo,etc, mi pregunta es solamente es son reglas lógicas para que el documento tenga un orden lógico o solamente para tener un orden lógico jerarquíco?

Comment: @Pablo yo me refiero que si son reglas logícas o jerarquías de quién tiene más poder que otro , entiendes?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con reglas lógicas y jerárquicas? A lo que se refiere el párrafo indicado es que no todos los atributos pueden usarse en todas las etiquetas y no todas las etiquetas deberían ir dentro de cualquier otra. Existen ciertas reglas para eso. Si es a eso a lo que te refieres con reglas lógicas y jerárquicas, entonces HTML presenta ambas.

Comment: Si exacto:) solo busco la opinión de otro desarrador porque yo  andaba pensando lo mismo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En el mismo párrafo de donde extrajiste la cita que mencionas, también dice:

> HTML tiene un conjunto definido de elementos y atributos los cuales pueden ser utilizados en un documento , cada uno diseñado con un propósito específico y con su propio significado.

HTML tienes elementos para:

- Encabezados
- Párrafos
- Tablas
- Listas
- Enlaces
- etc.

Lo anterior es el vocabulario de HTML; a través de etiquetas

Del mismo modo el documento citado te indica que:

> HTML es una **estructura** tipo árbol (que conocemos como el DOM) que se forma a partir de sus etiquetas en las cuales todos los elementos tienen un padre definido; menos los elementos raíz

Entonces es importante distinguir que HTML nos brinda una sintaxis para crear una **estructura** de marcado a través de sus etiquetas; las cuales son interpretadas por el el motor de render de cada navegador.

Es importante saber además que existen reglas para saber que etiquetas pueden o no contener a otras

- Fuente 1: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/
- Fuente 2: Dada la extensión de la información, te dejo la especificación en esta [fuente respecto a semántica y estructura](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#dom) para revisar sobre la jerarquía

Comment: Gracias por tu opinión :) yo está pensando lo mismo sobre que sencillo es un orden lógico de cómo y dónde se pueden agregar correctamente las etiquetas de HTML5 porque no se pueden agregar a lo loco  porque por ejemplo no puedes meter un div dentro de un p bueno si puedes pero no tendría un orden lógico debería ser Primero un div y luego el p, gracias  sólo quería la opinión de alguien mas